# Affect another element in current outer element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="test">
 <button>Example</button>
 <div class="example" style="display:none;">Blah</div>
</div>

<div class="test">
 <button>Example</button>
 <div class="example" style="display:none;">Another</div>
</div>
```

When `button` gets clicked, I want `.example` to `.show`, but only the `.example` that's in the current `.test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do exactly what you said:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.test').find('.example').show();
});
```

This works too for the markup you posted, but it won't work if the button and `.example` are not siblings:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.example').show();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way that works for your particular HTML:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.example').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiya **Working demo** for your case here: http://jsfiddle.net/4bLZF/

this uses `slideToggle` http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

**code**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    // Watch for clicks on the "slide" link.
    $('button').click(function () {
        $(this).next(".example").slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });


});​
```